# Sphinx server turning off/stopping on its own

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

Has anyone else had problems with a sphinx search just stopping or turning off on its own? I've set up a delta index to keep the index up to date. Every few days Sphinx will shut down and I'll have to go back and restart it.

Can a delta index some how trigger Sphinx to turn off?

Answer (score 0):

Are you restarting your machine? Because Sphinx doesn't automatically boot up when your system does.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but my hosting service might be. I have a cron job that basically just keeps the application awake. I had to use Passenger to upload and need to keep the application constantly running anyways. Otherwise when it reloads, it's super slow when Passenger starts back up.

Comment: Perhaps check by running `uptime` in a shell on the server?